# How to force applet to use Browser Settings for proxy

Tags: java, proxy, applet

In client computer, control panel\java\network settings\proxy configuration--> direct connection is selected for proxy.
**how can i force the applet to use the browser settings for proxy instead?** Applet is signed and compiled with java1.6